# Self Join in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have read some same question but i don't get any solution. I have one table name "Category". I have three column id, parent_id, name. I want to display records with parent_id name.

**Right now records are displaying like....**

```
id   parent_id   name
1        0       Mobile
2        0       TV
3        1       Samsung
```

**But I want...**

```
id   parent_id         name
1        0             Mobile
2        0             TV
3        Mobile        Samsung
```

**I tried** **this** but it display error **Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'category'**

```
DB::table('category')->join('category','category.id','=','category.parent_id')->where('category.parent_id','>',0)->get();
```

**I have solved my proble by this query.....**

```
$sql = "select category1.name as name1, category2.name as name2, category1.id,category1.parent_id";
$sql .= " from category as category1 left join category as category2 on category1.id=category2.parent_id where category2.parent_id >0";
return DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: That's not inner join please read about joins   [1]: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vivekssqlnotes/2010/01/02/sql-joins_2D00_-inner-joins_2C00_-self-joins_2C00_-outer-joins_2C00_-cross-joins/

Comment: @basheer sir thanks.... but any idea in my query ?

Comment: DB::EnableQueryLog(); and after runing query dd(DB::getQueryLog());
print your query and you will come to know what laravel is doing behind the scene..

Comment: print sql format query....

Comment: OK I HAVE SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANKS TO Basheer Kharoti and Satisfaction for your reply and suggestions.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: i change the query as i mention in my que...(EDITED).

Comment: That's not actullay laravel solution try using laravel RAW queries or Eloquent to get it done... Also I've edited my question check it out if it works for you....

Comment: yes sir you r right. can you convert that  ?

Comment: check out I've edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try following query

```
$result = DB::table('category as c1') 
->leftJoin('category as c2','c1.id', '=', 'c2.parent_id')
->where('c1.parent_id','>',0)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
   $result = DB::table('category as c1') 
->join('category as c2','c1.id', '=', 'c2.parent_id')
select(
    'id',
    'name',
    DB::raw('( case when c1.parent_id > 0 then c2.name ELSE c1.parent_id End ) as "parent_id"'),
    ->get();
```